# Can Konohamaru summon the Monkey King Enma?

Tags: naruto

Has it been revealed what Konohamaru's summons is? Did he inherit his grandfather's summons or did he show an affinity for frogs?

Comment: At the beginning of December, we will see the next bell test which will likely contain Konohamaru. We'll get to see some more abilities then

Comment: It is revealed that Konohamaru does in fact summon monkeys in the boruto anime, latest episode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Can Konohamaru summon the Monkey King Enma?**

Maybe. We can't be sure until we see it.

**Has it been revealed what Konohamaru's summons is?**

No.

**Did he inherit his grandfather's summons or did he show an affinity for frogs?**

We can assume none of them for now. Same as Asuma Sarutobi who didn't summon Enma or any other summoning animal either.

---

If I still have to make a wild bet then I will assume it's frog as Konohamaru is more of Naruto's follower and never seen trying to do any of his grandfather's Jutsu. And remember his grandfather was not around to pass on the contract to him and we never see any other Monkey King summoner who can teach him that but Naruto is still there.

---

In *Boruto: Naruto Next Generations* episode 4, we see he can summon toads and he summons [Gamagorō](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Gamagor%C5%8D).

[image]

Comment: To add to the same answer... Summoning cannot be inherited unless you make a blood contract with a summoning type.

Comment: There is some missing info. Konohamaru does summon a Monkey by the name of Enra as mentioned in a different answer

Comment: @StackUpPhysics I have stopped watching Boruto and somebody has already done the effort.

Comment: @AnkitSharma yeah I commented after seeing that answer and same I also left it due to these boring spoilers

Answer (score 3):

No, Konohamaru cannot summon Enma as he hasn't made a contract yet. It is true that his grandfather had, but for him to be able to summon Enma, he has to sign a blood contract too.

Comment: it looks like the boruto anime has made this answer obsolete.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like it has been confirmed in the Boruto anime that konohamaru does indeed summon toads.

[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AL0H98TM96I)

Answer (score 2):

Aside from his ability to summon toads, Konohamaru is also capable of summoning a Monkey named [Enra](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wN1we67f4sg), who from the looks of it is kin to the Monkey King Enma.

This is seen in Boruto Episode 119 where

> Konohamaru summons Enra to help in a battle, in order to perform a [Combo Sealing technique](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Combo_Seal:_Monkey_Yang_Suppression) on Soma.

[image]